# The method in the type is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android

I have structure:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(getActivity() != null)
        Intent intenta = StatisticsActivity.newInstance(this, (Question)mStream.get(position));
    startActivity(intenta);
}
```

I have issue

```
(Intent intenta = StatisticsActivity.newInstance(this, (Question)mStream.get(position))):
The method newInstance(Activity, Question) in the type StatisticsActivity is not applicable for the arguments (UserQuestionsFragment, Question).
```

`newInstance`:

```
public static Intent newInstance(Activity activity, Question question) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, StatisticsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(QUESTION_KEY, question);
    return intent;
}
```

Eclipse offers the change `newInstance`:

```
public static Intent newInstance(UserQuestionsFragment userQuestionsFragment, Question question) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(userQuestionsFragment, StatisticsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(QUESTION_KEY, question);
    return intent;
}
```

But it also raises an error.
What may be possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: hello in: Intent intenta = StatisticsActivity.newInstance(this, (Question)mStream.get(position))

Comment: A `Fragment` isn't an `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass `Fragment` into the `newInstance()` method, but it expects `Activity`.
In pre-eclipse-suggestion version change this

```
if(getActivity() != null)
    Intent intenta = StatisticsActivity.newInstance(this, (Question)mStream.get(position));
// Also, this line should be giving you a compiler error
// because you created intenta inside if clause, so
// it's not visible here
startActivity(intenta);
```

to this

```
Activity curActivity = getActivity();
if(curActivity != null) {
    Intent intenta = StatisticsActivity.newInstance(
    /* this is where the change is -> */ curActivity, (Question)mStream.get(position));
    startActivity(intenta);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) constructor in android does not take (UserQuestionFragments, XXX ) as arguments.

The constructors are below:

```
Intent()
Create an empty intent.

Intent(Intent o)
Copy constructor.

Intent(String action)
Create an intent with a given action.

Intent(String action, Uri uri)
Create an intent with a given action and for a given data url.

Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
Create an intent for a specific component.

Intent(String action, Uri uri, Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
Create an intent for a specific component with a specified action and data.
```

Hope this helps.